# Is there an easier way to do this with static variables?

Tags: php

I have some old code where I took functions like this:

```
function getDataPlain() {
  $theArray = fetchFromDb("select * from tablename");
  return $theArray;
}
```

and converted them to use static like this:

```
function getDataStaticVersion() {
  static $theArray;
  if (isset($theArray)) {
    return $theArray;
  }
  else {
    $theArray = fetchFromDb("select * from tablename");
    return $theArray;
  }
}
```

Then, if the method was called more than once it would only hit the database once.  This works well but I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way to do this with less code that has to be written in each function.  (I have a number of functions like this that I'd like to convert to the static version)

Comment: Looks reasonable: `static` is a perfectly good solution :)  You might also want to consider `global` and/or `$GLOBALS[]`, in conjunction with `isset()` : https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: I would strongly suggest at least wrapping this in a class definition to avoid polluting the global scope with unencapsulated variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the fact that the static variable is not set and null coalescing to load the value...

```
function getDataStaticVersion() {
  static $theArray;
  return $theArray ?? $theArray = fetchFromDb("select * from tablename");
}
```

So when it's not set it will run `fetchFromDb()`.

As an alternative, you could restructure the code slightly so that rather than an earlier return, you call the extra code on when the array is set and always return at the end...

```
function getDataStaticVersion() {
  static $theArray;
  if (! isset($theArray)) {
    $theArray = fetchFromDb("select * from tablename");
  }

  return $theArray;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nigel, that looks good as long as my code is a oneliner like in my example, but sometimes I have multiple lines of code to do the db fetch and other logic...

Comment: @Wes, added a slight change to your original code as an alternative.

Comment: Thanks, that's definitely cleaner than my original, and allows for more code to be written.